# Error trying to use bc in combination with octave output

Tags: bash, shell, octave, bc

I'm trying to run a calculation using bc, as you can see below.

The second variable (var2) however is the output of a .m-file using octave and has the format -1.23456

The first variable has the format 1.234.
When trying to run the calculation i get the error:

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ?
```

It's possible to change the value of `var2` manually and then it works. But it's not what i'm looking for. 
I think it's a problem with the type of the variable being returned from octave.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: Tried to write the value to a file and read it back in. But doesn't work either (same error as above)!

EDIT: MCVE

The test.sh file looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
function postprocessing(){                
##doing some postprocessing stuff here, this function already exists.
var2=$(octave evaluation.m)
}
##this is the part i want to edit
read var1 

postprocessing

Diff=$(echo "${var1}-(${var2})" | bc)
##depending on the result of $Diff, do some stuff here
echo $Diff
```

The evaluation.m file looks like this:

```
##calculate var2 here, this file already exists too.
var2=1-2.34567;
printf("%i\n",var2)  ##but also tried %f, %s
```

I'm running the script from terminal.

```
bash test.sh
```

or

```
./test.sh
```

I'm using GNU Octave 4.2.0.

Comment: Please add a complete MCVE which can be executed. Without this we can just guess. Btw, why do you use 'bc' if you also call GNU Octave?  You can just add var1 as argument so octave can add this into the calculation

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to run that piece of code? In the shell?

Comment: Did you try manually printing the value of var2 in the shell?

Comment: I'm running simulations on a hpc using bash. The simulation results are post processed using an already existing octave script. I'm trying to automate the process with a bash script. I will edit the post as andy suggested.

Comment: @BlackPearl yes, i printed it using ````echo $var2```` and it looks like a usual bash variable

Comment: Can you post the result of the print? I think there might be some issue in the value getting assigned.

Comment: @MikeR yes, I'm running the .sh file in the shell!

Comment: @BlackPearl It's a number as said in the post. The exact value for my test case right now is -5.407287

Comment: if you replace `var2=$(octave evaluation.m)` with `var2=$(echo 123.45)` does the rest of your script work? Btw, this isn't a MCVE because evaluation.m is incomplete. It also has syntax errors: the format string has to be quoted

Comment: @Andy i think you are close to solving the problem. It's not working when doing ````var2=$(echo 123.45)```` only if i do ````var2=123.45````.

Comment: anyone know how to solve this? Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: You've reached the point where you've scared all possible contributors because you aren't able to clearly define you problem. I'ts obvious that the error is on your side but you aren't able to provide a minimal (for example octave isn't involved here), complete (you are missing a shebang or show how you call your script) and executable script which shows your problem. This all is really essential to get good help

Comment: @Andy I edited the post. Instead of using ````bc```` i also tried using ````awk````. ````Diff=$(awk -v a="$var1" -v b="$var2" 'BEGIN {print a - b}')````. This helps with the error message, but the calculation is not done so ````Diff=$var1````

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the bash script (see [here](https://ideone.com/poAPES) for a reproduction with the octave script mocked up), I suggest calling `bash -x test.sh` to see exactly what `bc` command is executed, in particular what the `var2` expands to. The `^[` looks a lot like an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), for instance those that would be used to produce colored text in a shell, but octave should know better than to output them when its stdout isn't a terminal

Comment: This is the output when running bash -x test.sh. I hope it's readable!
````+ echo 'var1?'
var1?
+ read var1
2
+ postprocessing
++ octave test.m
warning: function ./test.m shadows a core library function
+ var2='-1.34567'
+ echo '-1.34567'
-1.34567
+ var2='-1.34567'
++ echo '2-(-1.34567)'
++ bc
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ?
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
+ Diff=
+ echo
````

Comment: Your MCVE works for me without problems.

Comment: @JohannesMaximilian any weird formatting on the output? From what I read it should definitely work, there's `echo '2-(-1.34567)'` which is piped into the `bc`, which certainly is valid. It might be a good idea to `cat -A test.sh` to check that there's no invisible chars in the expression you echo to bc, which could happen especially if you've copy/pasted from other sources

Comment: That `^[` is an escape character. Sounds like you're getting terminal control escape sequences in your `octave` output. Try redirecting `octave`'s output to a file and then using a hex dump like `od -c` to examine its contents and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I just realized if i run the program from a mac with terminal (ssh connection) it works, but running it from windows with terminal (using remote desktop connection) produces the error shown above.